# How to fix Ajax auto refresh with Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I want to refresh a part of the webpage automatically without refreshing the whole page. (say one division of webpage).

I have a script that calls a PHP page periodically.

Script:

```
<!----------- ********* AJAX code to auto refresh the part of a webpage************ --------->
<script langauge="javascript"> 
  function loadXmlHttp(url, id) {
    var f = this;
    if (loadXmlHttp.xmlHttp){
      f.xmlHttp = loadXmlHttp.xmlHttp();
      f.el = document.getElementById(id);
      f.xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
      f.xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){f.stateChanged();};
      f.xmlHttp.send(null);
    } else {
      alert('Your browser does not support AJAX!');
    }
  }
  loadXmlHttp.xmlHttp = null;
  loadXmlHttp.re = /^http/.test(window.location.href);
  /*@cc_on @*/ // used here and below, limits try/catch to those IE browsers that both benefit from and support it
  /*@if(@_jscript_version >= 5) // prevents errors in old browsers that barf on try/catch & problems in IE if Active X disabled
  try {loadXmlHttp.ie = window.ActiveXObject}catch(e){};
  end @*/
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest && (!loadXmlHttp.ie || loadXmlHttp.re))
    loadXmlHttp.xmlHttp = function(){return new XMLHttpRequest();}; // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari, others, IE 7+ when live - this is the standard method
  else if (/(object)|(function)/.test(typeof createRequest))
    loadXmlHttp.xmlHttp = createRequest; // ICEBrowser, perhaps others
  else {
    loadXmlHttp.xmlHttp = null;
    // Internet Explorer 5 to 6, includes IE 7+ when local //
    /*@if(@_jscript_version >= 5)
    try{loadXmlHttp.xmlHttp = function(){return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");};}
    catch(e){try{loadXmlHttp.xmlHttp = function(){return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");};}catch(e){}}
    @end @*/
  }
  loadXmlHttp.prototype.stateChanged = function(){
    if (this.xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && (this.xmlHttp.status == 200 || !loadXmlHttp.re)){
      this.el.innerHTML = this.xmlHttp.responseText;
      if(this.success){
        this.success();
      }
    }
  }
</script>
<!----------- ********* AJAX code to auto refresh the part of a webpage ends here************ --------->
```

And a Div where I am calling this function is something like this:

```
<div class="textad" id="text"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
      var statsrequest = new loadXmlHttp('display_text_ad.php', 'text'), repeat = arguments.callee;
      statsrequest.success = function(){setTimeout(repeat, 6000);};
    })();
  </script>
</div>
```

Now, this code is working fine with all browsers except Internet Explorer. (I have checked for Chrome, Mozilla, Opera and Safari). So, I need a little help fixing this bug with Internet Explorer. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it work only for first time?

Comment: Thanks in advance for all the help, im new to StackOverflow and im LOVING it! Any ideas/suggestions would be much appreciated. Please provide simple project. so can anyone has any idea about how to resolve this problem? Are there any suggestions on how to fix this wonderful issue? Any ideas?

Comment: @FAngel I am trying to call the php page "display_text_ad.php". And it is working fine with all browser except IE.

Comment: Again - what do you mean under `it is not working fine under IE`? In Chrome, Mozilla, Opera and Safari you see dancing ladies when your code is executed, but IE shows dancing gentlemen instead? Seriously - what's wrong with IE? What is not working?

Comment: @fAngel- Just relax. Don't be angry. I only mean to say that the automatic refreshing of page is not working in IE. It means it is not automatically calling the page "display_text_ad.php" after a specified interval of time. That's it.

Comment: What is version of your IE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your initial IE conditional compilation script is missing an '@' character. The `end @*/` line should instead be `@end @*/`.

It should be pointed out, however, that using JScript version browser detection is [not a good practice](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/06/10/same-markup-explaining-quot-jscript-version-quot-and-styling-new-html5-elements.aspx). A simpler, more robust approach would be to directly test for the standards you want to use and fall back to workarounds for legacy browsers. For example:

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // Use native XHR object for modern browsers
    loadXmlHttp.xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
    // Use the ActiveX control for legacy browsers
    loadXmlHttp.xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
else {
    // No XHR mechanism is available.
}
```

Comment: Plus, there may be a problem with encoding: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/the-problem-with-ie8-and-encoding-error-c00ce56e (I got this error if no `Content-type` specified)